# Adding to Access combobox that is based on table/query

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have an Access 2003 database that makes use of a combobox that contains a list of possible status codes. The codes are derived from a table and a stored procedure is used to return them as a recordset which is assigned to the combobox via code. The problem I am running into is how to add an additional status "ALL" to the combobox programatically. I do not want to add the status "ALL" to the table that contains the status codes but I do want it listed in the combobox. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using such a convoluted method for loading the data into your combo box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [dblookupcombobox has a null row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486299/dblookupcombobox-has-a-null-row/3486591#3486591)